# Countdown Timer with Progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is what i have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/BgEtE/

I am trying to get something like this: http://fusionmedia.dk/construction/

I need a progress bar like that and i need the days to be displayed like they have it. Also, i need to use a font called "Russel square" for the timer. I have looked all over but am having trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for the timer you can use [this one](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/) and you could integrate a progress bar, but I am not very sure.

This is [another great tutorial](http://www.script-tutorials.com/animated-jquery-progressbar/) that you could easily adapt to get what you want.

Well, I am not an expert but it's not so difficult, Take a look to this [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/codekmarv/FXnjb/29/). Pay attention to the default variables `// def values`

```
   var iCms = 1000;
    var iMms = 60 * iCms;
    var iHms = 3600 * iCms;
    var iDms = 24 * 3600 * iCms;
```

this what you need to use to "schedule" the progress bar in this section:

```
// def options
        var aDefOpts = {
            start: new Date(), // now
            finish: new Date().setTime(new Date().getTime() + 5 * iMms), // now + 5 days
```

For Example, if you write ...+5 * iMms it would be five minutes from now. `iDms => Days / iHms=> hours / iCms=> seconds`.

Also look at the css I've added in the demo, I think that to use a custom font, you first have to upload the font to your server, and then add the font in the style-sheet using something like this:

```
@font-face{
font-family: myFont;
src: url('myFont.ttf');
}

@font-face{
font-family: myFontEI;
src: url('myFont.eot');
}

Then Attach it as a font family like so...

font-family: myFont, myFontEI;
```

Comment: well, can you put together a jsfiddle

Comment: Well, this is just a copy and paste, but it should help you somehow: http://jsfiddle.net/FXnjb/

Comment: That has to be added in your stylesheet, butthe thing is I've never heard about that font. I just tried google fonts and it's not there.

Comment: ok, it is online though... also, i really do not understands that progress bar. Plus, i am only 14. Can you make it a little bit easier.